# How does the race condition in TOCTOU work?

Tags: java, multithreading, security, race-condition, secure-coding

The following code is supposed to be vulnerable to TOCTOU attack:

```
 public Period(final Date start, final Date end) {
    if (start.compare(end) > 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    }

    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;      // Class period has 2 private final member 
                         // variables Date start & end.

 }
```

What I fail to understand is that how will this race condition work? Say there are 2 threads T1 and T2 where T1 has a valid set of arguments and should pass the check and T2 is a hacker who wants to set invalid values in the class.

If 2 threads are racing and this piece of code is our critical section, then say T1 runs passes the check and sleeps. Now when T2 will start running won't it go through the check again (and fail)??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Comment: @JBNizet I was asking about "Time of Check Time of Use" bug. I don't have code for the threads, as I came across this discussion while reading Effective Java.

Comment: @DonalFellows I read the wiki before asking this question, I couldn't understand the use case explained there very well. assylias explained it very well in his answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `Date` is mutable, so another thread could change the end date: `end.setTime(0);` after you have checked that `start.after(end)` (easier way to write your condition).

So it would look like:

- T1: `start.after(end)` => returns false, all looks good
- T2: `end.setTime(0);` => sneaky Thread 2 changes the date
- T1: `this.start = start; this.end = end; //boom` => your class invariant is not valid anymore

Comment: It's worse than that. You don't need threads at all. An adversary can override `compare`, `after`, etc. Use `new Date(date.getTime)` or `java.time` is better. (There is no `Date(Date)` constructor. Don't use an overridable method here!)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Indeed, and actually the modification I mention does not even need to be interleaved - it could be made at any time in the future and still affect this object.

Comment: Thank you :) Going to the basics this happens because java object references are allocated from the heap (common to the threads) so using primitive member variables will help?

Comment: @user1071840 Assigning local `clone()`s of the passed-in `Date`s to the field variables and _then_ checking the ordering will help. The `final`s _do not help at all_.

Comment: I understand that. In fact using `clone()` will be unsafe too, as Date isn't a final class and clone() will allow unsafe children classes of Date to be set. A new defensive copy like this.start = new Date(start.getTime()) should work.